# How can I do a custom control login form in xPages?

Tags: authentication, custom-controls, xpages

I need to create a custom login form for login to Domino using xPages.

I need the login to be like a custom control so I can put it on every page.

so in case user are not logged in when they access my site they can choose to do so using the username and password fields provided at the top right

any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a short series of articles on using ajax to accomplish this. You can find links to the articles on the Domino Designer wiki.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/04022009013056PMWEBNJV.htm

While this is geared towards using a dojo dialog box to show the login fields you can use the same concepts if the login fields are always displayed in the banner.

Answer (score 2):

There are many many login controls on OpenNTF to choose from. A neat one is the Sliding in control from Declan lynch ;). ([sliding login on openntf](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Sliding%20Login%20Custom%20Control)) It works realy nice. If you take the link from declan from his answer and you take a look at his sliding login control I think can build yourself such a login.

Where it basicly comes down to is the following

1. Let the user fill in username/password
2. Get the username and password from the form fields
3. Do a dojo.xhrpost to names.nsf?login and send a redirect variable
   with you post.
4. On success check the url you are redirect to. If its the same as the
       redirect url you used to submit you only need to check cookies and
       your logged in.

Answer (score 1):

This login control by F. Kranenburg could help you.

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control

But, it does NOT show username and password fields when user is not logged in instead it shows a Login link which then opens a Dojo dialog showing the username and password fields.

Answer (score 1):

I know this may be a bit overdue but as I recently published a login custom control... maybe you'll be interested in my approach ;-)
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=dojo-login-dialog-custom-control

Comment: Oliver, I was looking for a way to get my (maybe old-style coded) login control running with IE 11 and newer...I tried your login control, it works perfect - thank you for sharing it !!