# XPages: Profile Switching

Tags: javascript, java, xpages, lotus-notes

I Have two User profile define in my Xpages project but i am  trying to
create a function that would make me to be able to switch between
the two user profile but i have no idea how to go about it

Comment: no the user profile just like  switching user in lotus note

Comment: are those different people, or the same user with different user names?

Comment: the same user could be diffrent name or the same name with diffrent profile setting

Comment: Please, update your question and specify as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch users for your application, you'll need to log out and log back in (which is what is effectively happening in the Notes client).

**However**, bear in mind that sessionScope is for the **browser** session, not the **user** session. But you can use this XSnippet to clear sessionScope http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=clear-session-current-nsf. Alternatively, your code can check the current effectiveUserName against one stored in sessionScope and, if different, reload all sessionScope variables.

Comment: I have a Switch Profile button that when clcked it bring out a dialog with the list of your profile then you select the one u want, to switch to so i want it to be able log the user automatically back in to the new profile

Comment: If you have the password, you can trigger a login from client-side code, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743095/how-can-i-do-a-custom-control-login-form-in-xpages

In theory, I think you should also be able to do a log in server-side in Java and return the relevant SessionID token, again if you have the password.

Without the password, user interaction is required, but a dialog could prefill a username box.